# zoom level with satellite imagery using google maps api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am having a problem where if I fit bounds to a single marker there is often no satellite imagery.

Is there a way I can set the map to the closest zoom level that still has satellite imagery?

I am using Google Maps API V3.

Answer (score 0):

getMaxZoomAtLatLng is how you could do it in V2.  Strangely it does not seem to be implemented in V3, as documented [here](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1624#c20)